# Entity Framwork code first - handling inheritence and composition

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm teaching myself Entity framework core.  Actually I'm relatively new to the whole .net world.

I've classes like below (apologies for the pseudo-code, actual code is too long to paste here).

```
Account
{
   User UserInfo {get;set;}
}

User
{
   string Email {get;set;}
}

Admin:Account
{
   // some properties
}
```

I'm trying to generate db tables using the EF code first pattern.  With the above classes, I've a seed routine that looks like below :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasData(
        new Admin
        {
            UserInfo = new User {Email = "abc@xyz.com"}
        });
}
```

With the above, when I try to create an initial migration, I get the below error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Account' cannot be added because the value provided is of a derived type 'Admin'. Add the derived seed entities to the corresponding entity type.

So, I changed the code like below (replacing Account with Admin):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Admin>().HasData(
        new Admin
        {
            UserInfo = new User {Email = "abc@xyz.com"}
        });
}
```

And now I'm getting this error (not sure where `UserInfoEmail` is coming from) :

> The seed entity for entity type 'Admin' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'UserInfo' set. To seed relationships you need to add the related entity seed to 'User' and specify the foreign key values {'UserInfoEmail'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.

I'm at a loss understanding this whole concept of handling relationships when using code first pattern. Can someone please help me understand what does the above errors mean, and how to handle relationships (esp composition & inheritence) when using EF code first pattern.

Comment: What are the primary keys for theses tables? Is `Email` a primary key? What do you want to achieve for `composition & inheritence`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second attempt was close, but you did one mistake:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Admin>().HasData(
    new Admin
    {
        UserInfo = new User {Email = "abc@xyz.com"}
    });
```

Look, here you set `UserInfo` to `new User`. Your error means that you cannot add `User` entity while trying to add `Admin` entity. Instead add `User` first and reference it from `Admin` entity later (looks like `Email` is your primary key in `User` entity):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(
    new User
    {
        Email = "abc@xyz.com"
    });
modelBuilder.Entity<Admin>().HasData(
    new Admin
    {
        UserInfoId = "abc@xyz.com"
    });
```

If you don't have `UserInfoId` in `Account` class, just add it:

```
class Account
{
    User UserInfo { get; set; }

    string UserInfoId { get; set; }
}
```